# Extend height of div without pushing other items lower?

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, ejs

I have a forEach loop set up that creates 1 linear flowchart per entry in a mongoDB collection. Since many of the entries have the same first entry (in screenshot, first 7 flowcharts all start with "PSUP"), so im trying to set it up so that only 1 title is shown if it repeats. I can't figure out how to extend the height to cover the rest of the spots with the same title. Sorry it's kind of hard to describe but I have a screenshot:

I tried to set the height manually, but then pushes the rest of the flowcharts lower. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

**EDITED with suggestion of an submitted answer**

```html
 <!-- Check if repeating; count number of times it repeats -->
 <% 
 var currentCol1 = "", count = 1;
 for (i = environments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
   if (environments[i].col1 == currentCol1){
     count++;
   } else {
     count = 1;
   }
   currentCol1 = environments[i].col1;
   environments[i].count = count;
 }
 currentCol1 = ""; %>

<!-- start loop through mongoDB collection: environments -->
<table class="environment" >
  <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
    <tr>
      <% if (currentCol1 != environment.col1){ %>
        <td rowspan="<%= environment.count %>"><%= environment.col1 %></td>
      <% } %>

      <td><%= environment.col2 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col3 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col4 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col5 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col6 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col6 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col8 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col9 %></td>
      <td><%= environment.col10 %></td>

      <% currentCol1 = environment.col1;

    }); %> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.environment td::after {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:0;
    width:45px;
    height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;    
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    content: "test"
 } 


.environment td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.8;
}
```

it now looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You could insert an empty `environment` div in that case, in an else-statement. And add a CSS-rule for `.environment:empty { border: none; background: none }`. In other words, an empty div with class `environment` would have the same width and height but no background or border.

Comment: @Greg do you know how I could go about extending the height of the PSUP box to cover that empty area without pushing the rest of the content down?

Comment: set a fiddle with your generated HTML + CSS pls

Comment: @ariel you didn't have to delete your entire answer lol